# OpenApi generator generates spring boot 2 server controller interface with incorrect(?) Flux / Mono response types

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I'm trying to generate controller interface with Flux / Mono types(I'm doing refactor to WebFlux).

Here is my openapi spec part:

```
/api/courses:
    get:
      tags:
        - RestCourse
      summary: Provides all courses
      operationId: getAll
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/ApiCourse'
```

Part of pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- RELEASE_VERSION -->
                <version>6.0.1</version>
                <!-- /RELEASE_VERSION -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <!--<templateDirectory>${project.basedir}/templates</templateDirectory>-->
                            <configOptions>
                                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                <!--<useSpringController>true</useSpringController>-->
                                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                                <sourceFolder>src/java/main</sourceFolder>
                                <modelPackage>spring.learn.api.model</modelPackage>
                                <apiPackage>spring.learn.api.controller</apiPackage>
                                <useTags>true</useTags>
                                <unhandledException>true</unhandledException>
                                <openApiNullable>false</openApiNullable>
                                <reactive>true</reactive>
                                <!--<library>spring-boot</library>-->
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Generated result is:

```
default Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<ApiCourse>>> getAll(...
```

But i think should be:

```
default Flux<ResponseEntity<ApiCourse>> getAll(...
```

Or I'm wrong?

Comment: motivate why it would be wrong

Comment: Ussually I see return type as Flux<ResponseEntity<ApiCourse>> . Therefore here is this question.
Can you motivate why it would be correct?

Answer (score 0):

These types are correct, I had the same question. Here's what the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-responseentity) has to say about it:

> `Mono<ResponseEntity<Mono<T>>>` or `Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<T>>>` are yet another possible, albeit less common alternative. They provide the response status and headers asynchronously first and then the response body, also asynchronously, second.